# CALayer: Single pixel line looks like 2 pixels

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-animation, core-graphics

This is my code:

```
int columns 3;
int columnWidth = self.layer.bounds.size.width / 3;

for (int c = 1; c < columns; c++) {
    CALayer *layer  = [CALayer layer];
    layer.frame = (CGRectMake(columnWidth * c + 0.5, 0.5, 1, self.layer.bounds.size.height));
    layer.backgroundColor = myColor;
    [grid addSublayer:layer];
}
```

I understand that I have to shift the x and y 0.5 pixels, which is what I have done, yet it still shows as a 2 pixel line instead of 1.

[image]

Comment: Keep in mind that on a Retina device, 1 point = 2 pixels.

Comment: @H2CO3 - I'm not on retina, but it's good to keep in mind. How would one differentiate between the two? Is there a constant? I thought perhaps cocoa would do all the translations automatically. But that's another subject.

Comment: Where do you draw the line? I Only see a rectangle (layer.frame) with width set to strange value of 1.

Comment: @AlexWien - It's a single pixel rectangle being drawn = a line. Is there a better way to draw a simple line?

Comment: @Wesley `[[UIScreen mainScren] scale]`

Comment: @H2CO3 - I'm on mac, doesn't look like that scale method exists on NSScreen mainScreen.

Comment: ad "translations automatically", Yes and if you set a point on 0.5 it will be between two points on an non retina one, leading to unsharp look.

Comment: make layer.frame width to 0.5

Comment: @LithuT.V - yes, that works, make it an answer so I can accept it. Why though does this work? And will it work the same on retina?

Comment: on a mac you can use `layer.contentsScale`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the layer Frame as

```
layer.frame = (CGRectMake(columnWidth * c + 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, self.layer.bounds.size.height));
```

Yeah it will work for retina also

Check this [post](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2033/core-graphics-101-lines-rectangles-and-gradients) Section **1 Point Lines and Pixel Boundaries**.It is well explained there

Comment: I didn't like the explanation in the link, so I created an illustration that shows the principle.

Answer (score 19):

I went ahead and made an explanatory picture, in case it's helpful to anyone

[image]

The lower line on exact pixel coordinates and will look blurry... each half of the width of the line lies in a different row of pixels...

The upper line is offset by `line_width/2.0` and will look sharp... it lies completely within a row of pixels.

Comment: Thank you for this powerful explanation!